# Iterating through <ng-template> generated HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to iterate through all the `<ng-template>` generated HTML elements and adding event listeners to it and `adding/removing` classes, but as I'm iterating through the elements it's not letting me grab the actual element.

Therefore, I can't grab stuff like `classList` or `innerHTML`

This is what the console throws:
`ERROR TypeError: item.classList is undefined`

Here is my `Template` Code :

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <h2 class="fw-semibold text-center pt-3 logo">bytenotes</h2>
  <button class="newCat-btn">+ New Category</button>
  <nav #catItem class="navbar-container">
    <h3
      *ngFor="let category of categories; first as firstCat"
      class="catItem"
      [ngClass]="firstCat ? 'active' : ''"
    >
      {{ category }}
    </h3>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my `Component` Code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css', '../../styles.css'],
})
export class NavComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('catItem') catItem!: ElementRef<HTMLHeadingElement>;
  categories: Array<string> = [];
  activeCategory: string = '';

  constructor(private db: DatabaseService, private auth: Auth) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let currUser = this.auth.currentUser?.uid || '';
    //Populate categories Array
    this.db.getCategories(currUser).then((data: any) => {
      let catArray = data.val();

      catArray.forEach((category: any) => {
        this.categories.push(category);
      });

    });
  }
  //Setting active class
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let navItems = this.catItem.nativeElement.childNodes;
    console.log(navItems);

    navItems.forEach((item: any) => {

      //Sets Active category
      if (item.classList.contains('active'))
        this.activeCategory = item.innerText;

      item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navItems.forEach((item: any) => {
          item.classList.remove('active');
        });
        item.classList.add('active');
        this.activeCategory = item.innerText;
        console.log(this.activeCategory);

        //Horizontal Scrolling only for smaller screen sizes
        if (window.screen.width < 1440)
          item.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'center' });
      });
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: Or you could just create a directive with the appropriate selector and `@HostBinding`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just use Angulars `routerLinkActive` directive

Answer (score 0):

instead of iterating through childNodes, which includes text nodes and others, use children which only includes HTML elements.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  let navItems = this.catItem.nativeElement.children;
  console.log(navItems);

  for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    let item = navItems[i];

    // Sets Active category
    if (item.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.activeCategory = item.innerText;
    }

    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      for (let j = 0; j < navItems.length; j++) {
        let innerItem = navItems[j];
        
        // Remove 'active' class from all items
        innerItem.classList.remove('active');
        
        // Your logic for adding the class or other operations goes here.
        // For example, to add 'active' to the clicked item:
        if (innerItem === item) {
          innerItem.classList.add('active');
          this.activeCategory = innerItem.innerText;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```